# Como apontar a pessoa mais velha em uma lista?

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde a todos, estou com uma duvida em relação aos meus estudos em Python.

Segundo o exercício proposto, devo criar um esquema de listas dentro de uma lista maior onde serão gravados sequencialmente, um nome e uma idade. Feito isso, devo apontar quem é a pessoa mais velha porém, estou com problemas ao tentar resolver isso.

```
dados = list()
listac = list()
maior = list()
cont = 0
while True:
   print('_'*15)
   dados.append(str(input('Nome: ')))
   dados.append((int(input('Idade: '))))
   listac.append(dados[:])
   dados.clear()
   cont += 1
   if cont == 3:
       break
print()
print(listac)
print()
for a in listac:
   print(f'{a[0]} tem {a[1]} anos de idade.')
print(listac)
```

Comment: qual é o problema? pode dar uma breve explicada? o que está ocorrendo de errado? qual é a sua duvida, especificamente?

Comment: Eu não consigo apontar a idade da pessoa mais velha, dentro desse exercício. Tentei usar max e min, mas não funciona.

Comment: Com o código, consigo até agora, criar uma lista para receber os nomes e suas idades, e cada nome e idade se dividem em listas. Ex: [ [Jean, 27], [Jonas, 25], [Caio, 13] ]. Três listas dentro de uma. O que consigo fazer até agora é puxar pelos índices, os nomes e idades. Ex: print(listac[0][0] que vai retornar Jean.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa primeiro ordenar seu campo `Idade` usando descending para depois fazer seu loop.

```
class Pessoa(object):
    def __init__(self, nome: str, idade: int):
        self.Nome = nome
        self.Idade = idade

dados = list()
listac = list()
maior = list()
cont = 0
while cont < 3:
   print('_'*15)
   nome = str(input('Nome: '))
   idade = int(input('Idade: '))
   pessoa = Pessoa(nome, idade)
   listac.append(pessoa)
   cont += 1
print()


listac.sort(key=lambda x: x.Idade, reverse=True)
print(listac, end='\n\n')

for a in listac:
   print(f'{a.Nome} tem {a.Idade} anos de idade.')
print(listac)
```

se você precisa do primeiro simplesmente acesse o index 0

```
pessoa = listac[0]
print(f'{pessoa .Nome} tem {pessoa .Idade} anos de idade.')
```